# Sending tokens to Actions On Google returns error "Can't parse the response. The response needs to be JSON format"

Tags: c#, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Good morning,
I am using ASP.NET HTTP API as Actions on Google fullfilment. I have an error message when I try to send tokens to Actions on Google project. Regarding to another question I read I made sure to have clear int value (not decimal) and it doesn't work.

My JSON which I send to Actions on Google:

`{"token_type":"Bearer","access_token":"edeaa27e-12b7-43a1-bc7c-e6bbf9af71c3","refresh_token":"4344383b-cf07-4d12-a5c2-44b6481f5f48","expires_in":86400}`

Error message:

```
{
    insertId: "1o7lj2bmu"
    jsonPayload: {
        @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.identity.accountlinking.type.AccountLinkingError"
        errorReason: "Can't parse the response. The response needs to be JSON format."
        response: {
            body: ""{\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"access_token\":\"edeaa27e-12b7-43a1-bc7c-e6bbf9af71c3\",\"refresh_token\":\"4344383b-cf07-4d12-a5c2-44b6481f5f48\",\"expires_in\":86400}""
            status: 200
    }
    step: "AUTH_CODE_EXCHANGE"
    }
    logName: "projects/smartlightproject-f47f4/logs/accountlinking-pa.googleapis.com%2Ferror"
    receiveTimestamp: "2022-07-12T12:32:40.739532642Z"
    resource: {2}
    severity: "ERROR"
    timestamp: "2022-07-12T12:32:40.539Z"
}
```

What's wrong with that JSON? Or maybe I should do it in some other way?
I will be very very grateful if you could help me with that.

Here's my code after some improvements:

```
var result_acceess_token = "edeaa27e-12b7-43a1-bc7c-e6bbf9af71c3";
var result_refresh_token = "4344383b-cf07-4d12-a5c2-44b6481f5f48";
var expires_expires_in = 86400;

var resultObj = new
{
     token_type = "Bearer",
     access_token = result_acceess_token,
     refresh_token = result_refresh_token,
     expires_in = expires_expires_in
};

return Ok(resultObj);
```

Earlier I tried to serialize JSON with JsonConvert and return it as JsonResult or raw string value.

Comment: How *do* you send the JSON response? Is it an actual JSON response in the first place? You didn't post any code so we can only guess. The error says you returned a quoted string instead of an actual JSON object. If you used `return Ok(someString);` instead of `return Ok(someObject);` you ended up sending a JSON string containing another string

Comment: Very thank you, your suggestion made me think and I found that my post method returned string instead real Result. I made it as ActionResult and sent an object instead of raw json string and it worked well :). So if I understand I can't send raw json string but instead of that I must send objects, right?

Comment: Where's your code? You mention an `ASP.NET HTTP API`. ASP.NET Web API serializes responses to JSON. If you return an object, it's serialized to JSON. If you return a string it's serialized as a JSON containing a single string. That's why the Web API tutorials don't contain explicit deserialization code.

Comment: I edited the question so the code is in the end of it. So if I understood you well every object returned as normal Content is serialized to JSON by default, right? I just didn't know what type of response I shoul use to send proper JSON as response.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the response you're sending back is the JSON as a quoted string. That is - there is a quote at the beginning and end of the JSON. While this *is* a valid JSON string (it is, after all, a quoted string), it sounds like it is looking for a JSON object.

Verify the body of the response and make sure it does not contain the opening and closing quotes.